# Exclude words from custom order - WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress

I would like to exclude some words from my titles when I am sorting them, for example, I would like to sort by last name:

John Black
John Smith

But I also have their titles, which are like: CEO, CFO, etc so it looks like this:

John Smith, CEO
John Black, CFO

I would like to exclude those and similar words from query so it just skips them.

Here's what I tried so far:

```
function posts_orderby_lastname( $orderby_statement ) {
  $post  ="post_title";
  $pieces = explode(",", $post);
  $post_title=$pieces[0];  
      $orderby_statement = "RIGHT($post_title, LOCATE(' ', REVERSE($post_title)) - 1) ASC";
      if($orderby_statement=='ACS'){
$orderby_statement = "RIGHT($post_title, LOCATE(' ', REVERSE($post_title)) - 3) ASC";


}
    return $orderby_statement;
}
```

I am stuck at adding the exclude...

Not sure how to proceed at all.